# Question about JavaScript Math.random() and basic logic

Tags: javascript, math, random, statistics

I wrote a simple piece of code to compare random array difference and found something ... that I don't quite understand.

1. I generate 2 arrays filled with random numbers
2. Add up the differences between the random numbers
3. Print out the average difference

I would have expected the result to be random number close to 0.5 but in practice, it is 0.3333.

Why does the random number array home in on 0.3 and not 0.5?

```js
const result = document.getElementById('result');
const generateRandomNrArray = (nrNumbers) => {
 let i;
 let result = [];
 for (i = 0; i < nrNumbers; i++) {
  result.push(Math.random());
 }
 return result;
}
const getArrayDiff = (arr1, arr2) => {
  var diff = 0;
  arr1.forEach(function (v1, index) {
      diff += Math.abs(v1 - arr2[index]);
  });
  return diff;
}
const run = (nr) => {
  const arr1 = generateRandomNrArray(nr);
  const arr2 = generateRandomNrArray(nr);
  const totalDiff = getArrayDiff(arr1, arr2); 
  
  result.innerHTML = "Average difference:" + (totalDiff / nr);
}
```

```css
button {font-size: 2em;}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<button id="run" onclick="run(1500)">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Java seems to do give the result too. Maybe this would help explain this behaviour? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637822/mean-of-absolute-difference-series-of-two-random-series-uniformy-distributed

Comment: Try it again with 3 numbers and see what your average is. You might see the pattern

Comment: The average difference probably tends to 0. You're talking about the absolute difference.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This basically boils down to a limit and it makes sense. Consider the combinations of numbers between 0 and 10 and count the various differences you can make.

For example, there is one combination with a difference of 9 — (0, 9). There are 5 with a difference of 5:

```
[0, 5],  
[1, 6], 
[2, 7], 
[3, 8], 
[4, 9]
```

But there are nine combinations with a difference of 1:

```
[1, 2], 
[2, 3], 

... 
[8, 9]
```

With 0 - 10 the counts are:

```
{1: 9, 2: 8, 3: 7, 4: 6, 5: 5, 6: 4, 7: 3, 8: 2, 9: 1}
```

There are 45 combinations and the average difference of the those combinations is `3.6666` not `5` because there are more smaller differences than larger ones.

When you increase the granularity from 0 - 10 to 0 - 100 the same pattern holds. There are 99 combinations that result in a difference 1 and only 50 with a difference of 50 for an average of `33.6666`.

As you increase the number of significant digits the opposite directions the opposite direction with finer and finer divisions between 0 and 1, you find the same process as the limit approaches `1/3`.  There are many more smaller difference than larger ones pulling the average difference down. For  `0-1` in 0.1 intervals you'll see 9 with a difference of 0.1 and 5 with a difference of 0.5, at 0.01 there will be 99 with a difference 0.01, and 50 with a difference of 0.5. As the interval approaches 0 the average of the differences approaches `1/3`.

Comment: Yeah, the problem becomes easier to understand with fixed larger numbers instead of small granular 0.xxxx numbers. 
"...because there are more smaller differences than larger ones" This is a good point, but it raises a few questions. Why isn't the average number even smaller then?, e.g 0.25. 
At first, i had a gut feeling that the number will end up being Math.PI for some magical Math reason.

Comment: @RainerPlumer When you split an interval into two parts randomly, the average size of the two parts is `1/2`. If you select two numbers randomly, you are splitting the interval into 3 parts and the average size of every part is `1/3`. The average difference between the two numbers is then `1/3`.

Comment: @Sulthan: Your comment is clearer and more concise than every answer here. It would be a good answer on its own.

Answer (score 25):

(As a matter of fact, you are not looking at the *differences*, but at the *absolute differences* between your random numbers. There is a difference. (Pardon the pun.))

If you have two independent uniformly distributed random variables `X, Y ~ U[0,1]`,  then their absolute difference `|X-Y|` will follow a [triangular distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution#Distribution_of_the_absolute_difference_of_two_standard_uniform_variables) with expectation 1/3. Everything is as it should be. This distributional result, as well as calculating the expectation, is a fairly standard homework problem in probability theory. The intuition directly follows [Mark's argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56417398/452096).

Here are histograms of the absolute and the non-absolute differences. On the left, you see how there is more mass for smaller absolute differences, which pulls the expectation down.

[image: triangles]

R code:

```
set.seed(1)
xx <- runif(1e5)
yy <- runif(1e5)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(abs(xx-yy),main="|X-Y|",col="grey",xlab="")
hist(xx-yy,main="X-Y",col="grey",xlab="")
```

(Incidentally, our sister site [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions) is a wonderful resource if you have a probability/statistics question.)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a geometric argument to demonstrate why the result converges to 1/3.

First, let's define f(x, y) = abs(x - y). What we need to prove is that, for X and Y being two independent random variables with uniform distribution in [0, 1], E(X, Y) = 1/3.

If we visualize the function f in 3D, as a height field over the square [0, 1] x [0, 1], the volume under f consists of two tetrahedra whose base is a half-unit square, and whose height is a unit high.

E(X, Y) is the volume under f. By the pyramid volume formula, each of the two tetrahedra has volume a*h/3 where a is its base area and h its height. That means each tetrahedron has volume 1/2 * 1 * 1/3 = 1/6, and therefore E(X, Y) = 2 * 1/6 = 1/3.

Answer (score 3):

There is an easy natural way to look at this:

If you have an interval, let's say `<0.0, 1.0>` and you randomly pick a number from the interval, you will essentially split the interval into two parts `<0.0, x>` and `<x, 1.0>`.
The average size of each part (over many random numbers) will converge to `0.5`.

Now, if you pick two random numbers from the interval, you are splitting the interval into three parts `<0.0, x>`, `<x, y>` and `<y, 1.0>` (`x < y`). If you calculate the average size of each part over many random numbers, it will converge to `1/3`.

The average difference between the two numbers is the average size of the part.

(originally a comment)

Answer (score 1):

with discrete variable approach

subdivide interval [0;1] in N elems (resp k=1 to N, `X` will take value `k/N`). Later on we will make N tend to infty

For given `X_k` (where `X` holds value `k/N`), compute avg distance, given by

```
avgDistance(k) = sum_{i=1}^k (k-i)/N P(Y=i) + sum_{i=k+1}^n (i-k)/N P(Y=i)
```

first term when y < x, second term when x < y

first term sums the distance between 0 and k so `1/N(k(k+1)/2)`, while second term sums the distance between 1 and N-k so `1/N(N-k)(N-k+1)`.
Moreover `P(Y=i) = 1/N` for all i (since `Y` is uniformly distributed)

thus

```
avgDistance(k) = 1/N^2 [ k(k+1)/2 + (N-k)(N-k+1)/2 ] = 1/(2N^2) [ 2k^2 + N^2 - 2kN + N ]
```

Finally

```
avgDistance = sum_{k=1}^N avgDistance(k) P(X=k) = 1/N sum_{k=1}^N avgDistance(k) = 1/(2N^3) sum [ 2k^2 + N^2 - 2kN + N ]
```

Idea is to simplify the sum like aN^3 + ...terms less than N^3, thus when N tends to infty we will simply get aN^3/(2N^3) + something which tends to 0

```
sum 2k^2 = 2(N(N+1)(2N+1))/6 ~ 4N^3/6
sum N^2 = N^3
sum -2kN = -2N(N(N+1)/2 ~= -N^3
```

Thus `a = 4/6` and `avgDistance = 1/3`